# Problems trying to install Ubuntu in my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install the Ubuntu in my laptop, but it isn't working.

I boot the pendrive and when I select the option to install or even just to try, it appears a screen with the logo of Ubuntu and some errors in the left side of the screen, while the screen keeps flashing.

I tried to read something and I managed to read: `Couldn't mount read-writing` and `the disk contains an unclean file system (0 0)`, but I tried a different version of Ubuntu and I still couldn't install it.

[image: boot mode]

[image: GRUB boot menu]

[image: boot messages]

Answer (score 0):

What Software do you use to write Ubuntu on usb key ?
I use [Balenaetcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)

and it always works

Comment: I tried the YUMI, Linux Live Usb Creator and Rufus but they didn't work!

Comment: I tryed them also, and have sometimes errors. Since i use Balenaetcher i never had errors again. Works with Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: I'll try, I downloaded it now and let's see what will happen

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Perhap's try to open disk utility and format the USB Key to FAT

Comment: Try to format USB key to FAT and download a new ubuntu file or to use new USB key